# What is the best way to implement padding at the root of a react native app?

Tags: react-native, padding, styling

I would like to add margins/padding at the root of my app so that I do not have to include padding screen-by-screen.

My current entry point looks like this

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };

    //blah blah blah

  render() {
    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}
```

The entry point is currently handling the navigation to each screen throughout the app.  Is there a way to drop styles into the root so that the parent view of every screen includes padding?

I'm currently styling screens individually, which I would rather simplify to avoid repetition, for example with a `styles={styles.container}` in the parent View on each screen.

My app is only about 6 screens, so the solution for global padding does not have to be the *leanest solution possible*, but something at the top level would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to add padding to the content only. If you apply to navigator, your header and tabbar could be padded too.
You could define a `Content` component like this

```
function Content(props) {
  return (
    <View {...props} style={[{ padding: 10 }, props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  )
}

function YourScreen() {
  return (
    <Content>
      <Text>This is content</Text>
    </Content>
  )
}
```